# How to cast a nested LINQ query into a rectangular array?

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array

While learning C# by going through Project Euler (currently problem 11), I stumbled upon the problem that there doesn't seem a good way to turn a nested LINQ query into a rectangular array.

My code currently generates a jagged array. Is there any way to have a rectangular array as result?

```
      string dataString =
            "08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08"+
            "49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00"+
            "81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65"+
            "52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91"+
            "22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80"+
            "24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50"+
            "32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70"+
            "67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21"+
            "24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72"+
            "21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95"+
            "78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92"+
            "16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57"+
            "86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58"+
            "19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40"+
            "04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66"+
            "88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69"+
            "04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36"+
            "20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16"+
            "20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54"+
            "01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48";

        const int substringLength = 20 * 2 + 19;
        return Enumerable.Range(0, dataString.Length/substringLength)
                         .Select(i => dataString[(substringLength*i)..(substringLength*(i+1))])
                         .Select(s => s.Split()
                                       .Select(elt => int.Parse(elt))
                                       .ToArray())
                         .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to convert *jagged* array `T[][]` into *2D* one `T[,]` you have to loop:

```
private static T[,] To2DArray<T>(T[][] array) {
  if (null == array)
    return null; // Or throw ArgumentNullException

  T[,] result = null;

  for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i) {
    T[] line = array[i];

    if (array[i] == null)
      throw new ArgumentException($"Line #{i} is null", nameof(array));

    if (result == null)
      result = new T[array.Length, line.Length];

    if (line.Length != result.GetLength(1))
      throw new ArgumentException($"Line #{i} is not equal to 2D array width", 
                                    nameof(array));

    for (int j = 0; j < line.Length; ++j)
      result[i, j] = line[j];
  }

  return result ?? new T[0, 0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want strong typing, you can create your own extension method `To2DArray`:

```
public static class IEnumerableExt {
    public static T[,] To2DArray<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, int? numRows = null, int? numCols = null) {
        if (!numRows.HasValue)
            numRows = src.Count() / numCols;
        else if (!numCols.HasValue)
            numCols = src.Count() / numRows;

        if (!(numRows.HasValue || numCols.HasValue))
            throw new ArgumentException("One of numRows or numCols must be specified");

        var ans = new T[numRows.Value, numCols.Value];

        var srcE = src.GetEnumerator();
        for (int rowPos = 0; rowPos < numRows; ++rowPos) {
            for (int colPos = 0; colPos < numCols.Value; ++colPos) {
                srcE.MoveNext();
                ans[rowPos,colPos] = srcE.Current;
            }
        }

        return ans;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it to process your `dataString`:

```
const int substringLength = 3*20-1;
int rowCount = dataString.Length / substringLength;
var ans = Enumerable.Range(0, rowCount)
                    .SelectMany(rowNum => dataString.Substring(rowNum*substringLength, substringLength)
                                                    .Split()
                                                    .Select(s => int.Parse(s)))
                    .To2DArray(rowCount, 20);
```

(Note: This code is really making me wish for more `Span` support - such as `ReadOnlySpan<char>.Split` and `IEnumerable<ReadOnlySpan<T>>` and `ReadOnlySpan<char>.ToInt32`.)